# Room Booking Management System Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am developing a DB Design for Conference Meeting Room Booking System.

I am stuck in making Relationship between Rooms & Facilities Entity. There are Facilities (Equipment) like Projector, VoIP, AC etc in each room.  How to assign total no. of each equipment per room ?

Example : If I search for Room with 1 VoIP then I should get that Room & If I search for Room with 3 VoIP & 2 AC it will display that room.

Current DB Design

```
Room ID    Room Name   Facility ID

 1.          R1        11
 2.          R2        14

Facility ID    AC    VoIP    Projector
11.            1      3       1
12.            2      1       0
```

Please help me to make it better. I want to use join less as much as possible.

Any Help would be appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a many to one relationship or a "has many". Without typing out your code for you I will give you the basic design concept:

You should have a table for rooms with an id as a primary key(and other relevant details).

For example
Rooms:

```
        id
        roomName
        otherData
```

Use a second table for facilities. This table should have a primary key id for each individual piece of equipment and then a foreign key called RoomId which will have the value that corresponds to the primary key for the room it is connected with.

Facilities:

```
         Id
         roomId
         name
         cost
         otherData
```

Each facilities entry will have its own id, a roomId with will be the same value as the id for the room it belongs to(the id from the rooms table).

This way you can have 5 facilities connected to one room, 4 connected to another, zero connected to another 50 connected to another one etc.

In answer to your follow up question about selecting all rooms with for example 2 VOIP facilities:

```
     SELECT Count(name) FROM facilities WHERE name = "VOIP" GROUP BY roomID
```

This query will return a result that counts how many VOIPs are in each room. Now throw this in your WHERE in your query.

```
   SELECT * FROM room JOIN facilities ON id = roomId
   WHERE (above query) = 2;
```

Comment: but it will only show that Room contains that Equipment or not. I aslo want to display how many no. of equipment is present per room. Ex : In Room with Id 101 there are 5 AC and 2 VoIP. where to define Equipment Quantity no. & how to map it with Room Entity

Comment: This is how you do that. You join the tables on id = roomId and then count and group by room. If you want 2 of the same facility in one room no problem, just add both to the facilities table. They will have a distinct id so they will count as separate entities

Comment: SELECT * FROM rooms JOIN facilities ON id = roomId WHERE facilities.name = "VOIP"        For example is how you could select every room with VOIP. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. But as one room have more than one facilities and in different quantity how would I pass query for it. Ex :  I want room with 2 AC and 1 VoIP.

Comment: This is the correct design for that, as for the query you would have to put those restrictions in your WHERE clause. You can put a SELECT in the WHERE clause to return a count of the VOIP facilities i will edit my answer....

Comment: what if I have lots of equipment(s) and user is searching for room with the query as I have described earlier with more criteria then it will perform many queries which will create many DB Hits. It will create performance issues. As the project is developed in Liferay I want to use less Join as possible. Thanks for your guidance...